# caching system with search query option

Tags: caching, ehcache, terracotta

I am looking for a distributed cache solution that will also support some sort of basic query languages like "get the objects which has object.id > 10" kind of.
I did a hands on with terracotta enterprise edition it is perfectly fit but again it is paid one. Do we have any sort of caching system which meets the above requirement?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [redis](http://redis.io/), I think it may be exactly what you need.

The query syntax is pretty powerful. Redis supports master/slave replication, but it's so fast you can get quite far without ever needing it (on a properly specced server).